# Line wrapping on narrow pages

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

I'm trying to format a long paper of mine for the kindle.  The following works, but there's a problem.

```
 \usepackage[paperwidth=9cm, paperheight=11.5cm, top=0.1cm, left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
```

Sometimes if a line break is needed in the middle of a word and LaTeX doesn't like the break locations (i.e., it would cause underfull box rather than overfull), it doesn't bother with a hyphen or word wrap.  This makes some words run right off the edge of the screen.

How can I convince LaTeX to wrap there and have an underfull line rather than having words run right off the edge of the page?  That later seems quite a lot worse to me.

I'd rather not have to hand tune each line, since the usual format is a regular page, not a kindle page — this is just for proofreading on the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `\sloppy` at the beginning of your document. This sets the value of `\tolerance`, which TeX uses as part of its linebreaking and hypehenation rules, to 9999.  This will allow really 'bad' breaks, from a TeX point of view, but may solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm, paperheight=11.5cm, 
            top=0.1cm, left=0.1cm, right=0.1cm, 
            bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

A verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrry loooooooooooooong \mbox{woooooooord}
\blindtext

\begin{sloppypar}
A verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrry loooooooooooooong \mbox{woooooooord}
\blindtext
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]