# How to deal with bad line-wrapping of \texttt?

Tags: line-breaking

If I have long words inside `\texttt` blocks, in my case for writing about variable names, sometimes the word-wrapping doesn't quite work, resulting in slightly-too-long lines.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Most of the time, LaTeX line-wrapping works fine.  However, sometimes when I'm writing about code with lots of \texttt{long\_monospace\_variables}, \texttt{the\_line\_wrapping} doesn't quite get the position correct resulting in slightly-too-long lines.
\end{document}
```

[image: A PDF generated from the previous code. The second line is too long.]
I can manually insert `\linebreak`s to fix this, but that feels clunky.  Are there any better options?

Comment: How would you expect `\texttt{long\_monospace\_variables}` to be broken?

Comment: @Manuel without mercy. If there is no whitespace to break at anyway, the only way is to break at the last character before it becomes too wide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you want the variables to be broken, you can define a macro that allows breaking with certain rules. Here I just allowed breaking after `_`. Apart from that, you use a more semantic command that you can redefine with flexibility.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand*\ttvar[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\dottvar\detokenize{#1}\relax}}
\newcommand*\dottvar[1]{\ifx\relax#1\else
  \expandafter\ifx\string_#1\string_\allowbreak\else#1\fi
  \expandafter\dottvar\fi}

\begin{document}

Most of the time, \LaTeX{} line-wrapping works fine. However, sometimes when
I'm writing about code with lots of \ttvar{long_monospace_variables},
\ttvar{the_line_wrapping} doesn't quite get the position correct resulting in
slightly-too-long lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if my `veryLongVariableIsCamelCase`?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answers to this question

[Line wrapping on narrow pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15478/line-wrapping-on-narrow-pages)

it seems that the best way to do this is to wrap the offending paragraph in a `sloppypar` environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
Most of the time, LaTeX line-wrapping works fine.  However, sometimes when I'm writing about code with lots of \texttt{long\_monospace\_variables}, \texttt{the\_line\_wrapping} doesn't quite get the position correct resulting in slightly-too-long lines.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image: A PDF generated from the text. The long line issue has been fixed by the use of sloppypar.]

Using a `\sloppy` command has a similar effect for the whole document, but this seems a little dangerous since it could break formatting elsewhere.

Comment: Nope. Use `flushleft` instead, preferably from `ragged2e`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks. If you want to write up an answer, it would be great to see how `flushleft` is used, and what effect it has on the text.

Comment: `flushleft`, unfortunately, gets rid of indentation, and puts undesired whitespace below and above the paragraph.  `sloppypar` worked great for me.

Comment: Put in flushleft, syntax error. Sloppypar doesn't deal with long filename, it seems to wrap on a space.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to do with the `url` package. I define a `\longvar` command which does the job:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\longvar[1]{\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=100
\mathchardef\UrlBigBreakPenalty=100\url{#1}}

 \begin{document}

Most of the time, LaTeX line-wrapping works fine. However, sometimes when I'm writing about code with lots and lots of \longvar{very_long_monospace_variables}, \texttt{the\_line\_wrapping} doesn't quite get the position correct resulting in slightly-too-long lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had the same problem, and was suggested to reword the line so that the `texttt`s don’t end up on the same line.

There’s [another workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288168/43807) which is to do…

```
\emergencystretch 5em%
```

… with the caveat that 5 em is already very large. This is extra stretch used to justify text in order to try and make it fit, so basically the whitespace between the words on the lines can, in emergency cases, be made larger.

Too large and it looks bad, though, so use a small-ish value and manually reword the line to make it fit is the way to go. (A bit sad that one has to do this in 2019, but I admit I wouldn’t know how to programmatically do it either.) Deploy a small emergencystretch for the simple cases, then proofread the document.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I particularly like this solution because it does not involve manually defining areas where you might need to break a line, such as using a `sloppypar` section, and it does not require you to define characters where a line break is allowed. This is handy because when you write a document it is often not linearly from the beginning to the end.

Comment: sloppypar wont work with long filenames where there is no spacing.