# Line Feed in monospace font - Macro

Tags: macros, typewriter

I want to have long texts without spaces written in monospace font (using `\texttt`). As line feeds don't appear automatically, I found this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315376, where a macro is suggested.

As I want the text to break at several different symbols, I tried to change the macro to accept a parameter with the sign to break at. Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly, as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of rendered text]

Here is my version of the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\ttcomma[1]{\texttt{\expandafter\dottvar{\detokenize{#1}}{,}\relax}}
\newcommand*\dottvar[2]{%
\ifx\relax#1\else%
  \expandafter%
    \ifx\string#2#1%
      \string#2\allowbreak%
    \else#1
    \fi
\expandafter\dottvar\fi
}

\begin{document}
Some normal Text \ttcomma{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALineFeedAndBreakToTheNextLine}

\end{document}
```

Where did I go wrong? Bonus question: How can I change the macro to do a line break at several different signs (e. g. `,`, `:`, `-`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an `expl3` implementation, where you can set the allowed break points at runtime.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ttlong}{O{\c_silvernak_ttlong_breaks_str}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \ttfamily
  \silvernak_ttlong:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

% the default break points
\str_const:Nn \c_silvernak_ttlong_breaks_str { , : - }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \silvernak_ttlong:nn
 {
  \str_set:Nx \l__silvernak_breaks_str { #1 }
  \str_map_function:nN { #2 } \__silvernak_ttlong_char:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__silvernak_ttlong_char:n
 {
  #1
  \str_if_in:NnT \l__silvernak_breaks_str { #1 } { \skip_horizontal:n { 0pt } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  Some normal Text \ttlong{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALine-FeedAndBreakTo:TheNextLine}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{
  Some normal Text \ttlong[,]{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALine-FeedAndBreakTo:TheNextLine}
}

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{
  Some normal Text \ttlong[,:-a]{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALine-FeedAndBreakTo:TheNextLine}
}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` here is only used to force as many line breaks as possible.

[image]

The idea is to map the given string character by character; if the current character is in the list of allowed line break points, add a zero skip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following, just add every character you want to be breakable to the definition of `\breakable` (inside the `\detokenize`, this is done so that the category codes are correct). The entire text is you input is `\detokenize`d, and spaces are ignored inside the text.

**EDIT:** I somehow forgot to put a `\ttfamily` into the macro...

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\breakables{\detokenize{,:-.}}
\def\end@ttbreakable{\end@ttbreakable}
\newif\if@ttbreakable@break
\def\my@fi@gt\fi#1#2{\fi}
\newcommand*\ttbreakable[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \ttfamily
    \expandafter\@ttbreakable\detokenize{#1}\end@ttbreakable
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand*\@ttbreakable[1]
  {%
    \ifx\end@ttbreakable#1%
      \my@fi@gt
    \fi
    \@firstofone
    {%
      #1%
      \def\@ttbreakable@test##1#1##2\end@ttbreakable
        {%
          \if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax
          \else
            \allowbreak
          \fi
        }%
      \expandafter\@ttbreakable@test\breakables#1\end@ttbreakable
      \@ttbreakable
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hsize=5cm
\ttbreakable
  {%
    This is some text, with no spaces, but commas.
    It has: colons- hyphens and .periods, too.
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With some side effects you could do this with the `url` package. The text is treated as verbatim though which may not be what you want. But at least it provides an existing interface to set up the breaks.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\DeclareUrlCommand\ttbreakable{%
  \def\UrlBreaks{\do\,\do\:\do\-}%
  \def\UrlBigbreaks{}%
  \def\UrlNoBreaks{}%
  \def\UrlOrds{}%
  \def\UrlSpecials{}%
  \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily}}

\begin{document}

% Need a sloppy par otherwise the first line is too underfull and won't break
% at the first comma
\begin{sloppypar}
  Some normal Text
  \ttbreakable{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALine-FeedAndBreakTo:TheNextLine}
\end{sloppypar}

\parbox{0pt}{%
  Some normal Text
  \ttbreakable{someLongTextWithoutSpacesButWithCommas,WhereIWantToGetALine-FeedAndBreakTo:TheNextLine}}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]